# Unable to load the images in the jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a simple jsp page in the spring mvc project. But i am unable to load the images from the image folder. I tried with Real path and Context path still I am unable to load the images in to the jsp file.

**Real path:**

```
<%
 String realPath = application.getRealPath("/");
%>

 <img src="<%=realPath%>images\logo.png" alt="student" title="student">
```

**Context Path:**

```
<%
 String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
%>
 <img src="<%=realPath%>images\logo.png" alt="student" title="student">
```

My project folder struture looks like

[image]

Did I miss something? Do I need to make any configurations in the web.xml?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You must configure your static resources like images, js and css files like that:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"/>
```

In the above example, any requests from this url pattern /images/**, Spring will look for the resources from the /images folder.

Comment: Only needed if `/*` is mapped to Spring.

Comment: Thank you. It works for me. But I have small query. Let say I have 10 static resource folders (css, js, images.....), So do I need to map for all 10 folders? OR if I copy all the folders in the resource folder and configure only for resource folder like (<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/*"/>). Will that make sence? Any suggestion please

Comment: you can add many configuration for each file type for example :

<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/resources/js"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css"/>

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot use real path, because the browser will not be on the same machine as the webapp!!
2. You cannot use `\`, because URLs must use `/`.
3. Don't use Java code in JSP, especially when EL variables are there to be used.
4. You are missing a `/`. Quoting javadoc of [`getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29):

   > The path starts with a "/" character but does not end with a "/" character.

This is how to do it:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/logo.png" alt="student" title="student">
```